# shopify api using external database to override frontend information

Tags: php, shopify

Im new on shopify. My main question (i cannot find information about that in docs) is:

> apps -> are only to provide functionalities for administrators or we can develop apps that work
>   in frontend?

eg: If i have a product catalog in shopify, and I want to perform a price override from an external database to be displayed on the fly in catalog is this possible? As an example, i want to display different prices based on a calculation query to a local DB is this possible?.

> Additionally, do they have a bulk product upload programmatically or
>   foreach product we create is a new call to the api.

Answer (score 1):

> apps -> are only to provide functionalities for administrators or we can develop apps that work in frontend?

- Yes. Apps can be created to bring about a new functionality on the frontend, but their core operation works in the backside of the curtain.

*But that is not what you need for your requirement.*

If you use an external data to display the prices on the frontend, it only changes the price of what is display on the storefront. The effective price and the original price of the product remains same as the value which is fed in the shop's Shopify database.

> Additionally, do they have a bulk product upload programmatically or for each product we create is a new call to the API.

For any **POST/PUT** request you make to Shopify API, it allows you to add/update only one entity per call. In your case, you will have to make as many POST calls as there are number of products.

- Alternatively, you can use their CSV upload process for a bulk upload if you have all the information of the product catalog in hand.

Comment: thank you. one more question about prices. So I can display a different price but when the customer add to cart the original price will be added, and not  the price displayed in frontend?.

Comment: Yes. But, are you looking to display in multiple currency formats? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: my main idea is to know if shopify is suitable for development, where they offer cart services and I can develop the logic (eg: duties& taxes) from my side, communicating directly to the frontend and overriding the price the consumer must pay.